# C++ Python bindings cause "Access violation reading location 0x00000002"?

Tags: c++, python

I am using [the CGAL Python bindings for alpha shape](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Alpha_shapes_2/index.html).

**I have 8 arrays of `CGAL.Triangulations_2.Vertex` objects as follows:**

```
In [5]: len(alphaShapeVertices)
Out[5]: 8

In [6]: for i, asv in enumerate(alphaShapeVertices):
   ...:     print i
   ...:     print asv
0
[<CGAL.Triangulations_2.Vertex object at 0x03C423E8>, <CGAL.Triangulations_2.Vertex object at 0x03C42420>, <CGAL.Triangulations_2.Vertex object at 0x03C42458>, <CGAL.Triangulations_2.Vertex object at 0x03C42490>, <CGAL.Triangulations_2.Vertex object at 0x03C424C8>, <CGAL.Triangulations_2.Vertex object at 0x03C42500>, <CGAL.Triangulations_2.Vertex object at 0x03C42538>, <CGAL.Triangulations_2.Vertex object at 0x03C42570>, <CGAL.Triangulations_2.Vertex object at 0x03C425A8>, <CGAL.Triangulations_2.Vertex object at 0x03C425E0>, <CGAL.Triangulations_2.Vertex object at 0x03C42618>, <CGAL.Triangulations_2.Vertex object at 0x03C42650>, <CGAL.Triangulations_2.Vertex object at 0x03C42688>, <CGAL.Triangulations_2.Vertex object at 0x03C426C0>, <CGAL.Triangulations_2.Vertex object at 0x03C426F8>, <CGAL.Triangulations_2.Vertex object at 0x03C42730>, <CGAL.Triangulations_2.Vertex object at 0x03C42768>, <CGAL.Triangulations_2.Vertex object at 0x03C427A0>, <CGAL.Triangulations_2.Vertex object at 0x03C427D8>, <CGAL.Triangulations_2.Vertex object at 0x03C42810>, <CGAL.Triangulations_2.Vertex object at 0x03C42848>]
1
[<CGAL.Triangulations_2.Vertex object at 0x03C42880>, <CGAL.Triangulations_2.Vertex object at 0x03C428B8>, <CGAL.Triangulations_2.Vertex object at 0x03C428F0>, <CGAL.Triangulations_2.Vertex object at 0x03C42928>, <CGAL.Triangulations_2.Vertex object at 0x03C42960>, <CGAL.Triangulations_2.Vertex object at 0x03C42998>, <CGAL.Triangulations_2.Vertex object at 0x03C429D0>, <CGAL.Triangulations_2.Vertex object at 0x03C42A08>, <CGAL.Triangulations_2.Vertex object at 0x03C42A40>, <CGAL.Triangulations_2.Vertex object at 0x03C42A78>, <CGAL.Triangulations_2.Vertex object at 0x03C42AB0>, <CGAL.Triangulations_2.Vertex object at 0x03C42AE8>]
2
[<CGAL.Triangulations_2.Vertex object at 0x03C42B20>, <CGAL.Triangulations_2.Vertex object at 0x03C42B58>, <CGAL.Triangulations_2.Vertex object at 0x03C42B90>, <CGAL.Triangulations_2.Vertex object at 0x03C42BC8>, <CGAL.Triangulations_2.Vertex object at 0x03C42C00>, <CGAL.Triangulations_2.Vertex object at 0x03C42C38>, <CGAL.Triangulations_2.Vertex object at 0x03C42C70>, <CGAL.Triangulations_2.Vertex object at 0x03C42CA8>, <CGAL.Triangulations_2.Vertex object at 0x03C42CE0>, <CGAL.Triangulations_2.Vertex object at 0x03C42D18>, <CGAL.Triangulations_2.Vertex object at 0x03C42D50>]
3
[<CGAL.Triangulations_2.Vertex object at 0x03C42D88>, <CGAL.Triangulations_2.Vertex object at 0x03C42DC0>, <CGAL.Triangulations_2.Vertex object at 0x03C42DF8>, <CGAL.Triangulations_2.Vertex object at 0x03C42E30>, <CGAL.Triangulations_2.Vertex object at 0x03C42E68>, <CGAL.Triangulations_2.Vertex object at 0x03C42EA0>, <CGAL.Triangulations_2.Vertex object at 0x03C42ED8>, <CGAL.Triangulations_2.Vertex object at 0x03C42F10>, <CGAL.Triangulations_2.Vertex object at 0x03C42F48>, <CGAL.Triangulations_2.Vertex object at 0x03C42F80>, <CGAL.Triangulations_2.Vertex object at 0x03C42FB8>, <CGAL.Triangulations_2.Vertex object at 0x03C4D030>, <CGAL.Triangulations_2.Vertex object at 0x03C4D068>, <CGAL.Triangulations_2.Vertex object at 0x03C4D0A0>]
4
[<CGAL.Triangulations_2.Vertex object at 0x03C4D0D8>, <CGAL.Triangulations_2.Vertex object at 0x03C4D110>, <CGAL.Triangulations_2.Vertex object at 0x03C4D148>, <CGAL.Triangulations_2.Vertex object at 0x03C4D180>, <CGAL.Triangulations_2.Vertex object at 0x03C4D1B8>, <CGAL.Triangulations_2.Vertex object at 0x03C4D1F0>, <CGAL.Triangulations_2.Vertex object at 0x03C4D228>, <CGAL.Triangulations_2.Vertex object at 0x03C4D260>, <CGAL.Triangulations_2.Vertex object at 0x03C4D298>, <CGAL.Triangulations_2.Vertex object at 0x03C4D2D0>, <CGAL.Triangulations_2.Vertex object at 0x03C4D308>, <CGAL.Triangulations_2.Vertex object at 0x03C4D340>, <CGAL.Triangulations_2.Vertex object at 0x03C4D378>, <CGAL.Triangulations_2.Vertex object at 0x03C4D3B0>, <CGAL.Triangulations_2.Vertex object at 0x03C4D3E8>, <CGAL.Triangulations_2.Vertex object at 0x03C4D420>, <CGAL.Triangulations_2.Vertex object at 0x03C4D458>]
5
[<CGAL.Triangulations_2.Vertex object at 0x03C4D490>, <CGAL.Triangulations_2.Vertex object at 0x03C4D4C8>, <CGAL.Triangulations_2.Vertex object at 0x03C4D500>, <CGAL.Triangulations_2.Vertex object at 0x03C4D538>, <CGAL.Triangulations_2.Vertex object at 0x03C4D570>, <CGAL.Triangulations_2.Vertex object at 0x03C4D5A8>, <CGAL.Triangulations_2.Vertex object at 0x03C4D5E0>, <CGAL.Triangulations_2.Vertex object at 0x03C4D618>, <CGAL.Triangulations_2.Vertex object at 0x03C4D650>]
6
[<CGAL.Triangulations_2.Vertex object at 0x03C4D688>, <CGAL.Triangulations_2.Vertex object at 0x03C4D6C0>, <CGAL.Triangulations_2.Vertex object at 0x03C4D6F8>, <CGAL.Triangulations_2.Vertex object at 0x03C4D730>, <CGAL.Triangulations_2.Vertex object at 0x03C4D768>, <CGAL.Triangulations_2.Vertex object at 0x03C4D7A0>, <CGAL.Triangulations_2.Vertex object at 0x03C4D7D8>]
7
[<CGAL.Triangulations_2.Vertex object at 0x03C4D810>, <CGAL.Triangulations_2.Vertex object at 0x03C4D848>, <CGAL.Triangulations_2.Vertex object at 0x03C4D880>, <CGAL.Triangulations_2.Vertex object at 0x03C4D8B8>, <CGAL.Triangulations_2.Vertex object at 0x03C4D8F0>, <CGAL.Triangulations_2.Vertex object at 0x03C4D928>]
```

**I am trying to access the method `point()` of each object.**

**However, I can only do it until the 2nd array. From the 3rd onwards, I encounter an exception.**

```
In [7]: alphaShapeVertices[0][0].point()
Out[7]: Point_2(1.00000001401,2.90491385964e-290)

In [8]: alphaShapeVertices[1][0].point()
Out[8]: Point_2(3.96551377978e-164,3.05578113171e-151)

In [9]: alphaShapeVertices[2][0].point()

# HERE: python.exe has stopped working
```

The **screenshot** when exception occurs:

[image]

*As you can see, the exception **may not always happen at the 3rd** array. In the screenshot, it happens at 7th. I think it has something to do the memory allocation.*

The **debugger** tells me

> First-chance exception at 0x00000002 in python.exe: 0xC0000005: Access
>   violation reading location 0x00000002.
>
> If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely
>   continued.

I have being struggling for days. Could any one help me why and how to fix it?

---

---

## MWE

You may need to install [CGAL-Python (bindings for the Computational Geometry Algorithms Library)](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) (<kbd>CTRL+F</kbd> CGAL-Python), if you do not have it.

The `clusters` [data can be found here on pastie](http://pastie.org/8476863).

**With the data and library ready, run the following Python script:**

```
from sys import *
path.append("../../cgal_package")

from CGAL.Alpha_shapes_2 import *
from CGAL.Triangulations_2 import Delaunay_triangulation_2
from CGAL.Kernel import *

from random import *

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.font_manager import FontProperties

import constants

def Point_2_str(self):
    return 'Point_2'+str((self.x(), self.y()))
# now we turn it into a member function
Point_2.__str__ = Point_2_str


def getAlphaShape(cluster):
    list_of_points = [Point_2(e[0], e[1]) for e in cluster]
    L = []
    verbose = True

    a = Alpha_shape_2()
    a.make_alpha_shape(list_of_points)
    a.set_mode(Alpha_shape_2.Mode.REGULARIZED)
    a.set_alpha(1000)
    alpha_shape_edges = []
    alpha_shape_vertices = []
    for it in a.alpha_shape_edges:
        alpha_shape_edges.append(a.segment(it))
    for it in a.alpha_shape_vertices:
        alpha_shape_vertices.append(it)
    return alpha_shape_vertices

# get alpha-shape of each cluster
alphaShapeVertices = []
for cluster in clusters:
    alphaShapeVertices.append(alphashape.getAlphaShape(cluster))
# start testing
print alphaShapeVertices[0][0].point()
print alphaShapeVertices[1][0].point()
print alphaShapeVertices[2][0].point()
print alphaShapeVertices[3][0].point()
# somewhere around here the exception occurs
print alphaShapeVertices[4][0].point()
print alphaShapeVertices[5][0].point()
print alphaShapeVertices[6][0].point()
```

Comment: What happens if you `print(alphaShapeVertices[2][0])`?

Comment: @BasicWolf Pleaase see the updated screenshot. It may not always be alphaShapeVertices[2]. alphaShapeVertices[6] in the screenshot.

Comment: That is an obvious NULL pointer dereference. Use a debugger to find out what line of code is causing it.

Comment: As you can see, on the python side, there are indeed 8 array elements. I am accessing within the index 8.  On the C++ side, the source code cannot wrong, since it is a well-established library. So the error happens when I try to interface them together. I am wondering where the NULL pointer comes from?

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example that demostrate your problem. The fact that the library is well tested does *not* mean that *you* are using it correctly. If you provide some code that we can copy-paste and run in order to reproduce the behaviour it will be much easier to understand what's wrong.

Comment: @Bakuriu  Thanks a lot for the advice. Posted as suggested. Could you please kindly help? This question is a bit too tedious that I am afraid no one will help. Do please kiindly help! I really appreciate your help! :D

Comment: The bindings package you linked to is a beta version, and the project has not been maintained since 2009. Release notes say it was ported to CGAL 3.4. Maybe you have a newer version of CGAL?

Comment: @JanneKarila I myself am very new to bindings. WIth the deadline coming I really cannot bind it myself. So I can only be forced to use this version, whose window installed is directly provided there.

Comment: Yes but I suppose you have had to install CGAL itself separately, and you did not mention which version you have.

Comment: @JanneKarila  True true/ CGAL is seperately installed. Ver4.3

Comment: I'd try 3.4 then instead, based on what the release notes of the bindings say. (I have no experience with this library)

Comment: @JanneKarila  Oh so u mean a consistent version may help. I'd try.